# Display the member of one array depending on the other array

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array i and i want to show the array values if the name of same array repeat in the another array and have `true` value

my arrays like this

```php
    $array1 = [

   array(
    'name' => internal_evidence
    'price' => 30
    'course_id' => 3
    ),

   array(
    'name' => international_evidence
    'price' => 450
    'course_id' => 3
    ),

   array(
    'name' => internal_evidence
    'price' => 10
    'course_id' => 1
    ),

   array(
    'name' => technical_evidence
    'price' => 134
    'course_id' => 3
    ),


];


  $array2 = [

    array(
    'id' => 3
    'name' => graphic
    'price' => 150
    'attr' => array(
               'internal_evidence' => 'true',
               'international_evidence' => 'false',
               'technical_evidence' => 'true'
              )
   ),

    array(
    'id' => 5
    'name' => 3dmax
    'price' => 300
    'attr' => array(

              )
   ),

    array(
    'id' => 1
    'name' => ICDL
    'price' => 480
    'attr' => array(
               'internal_evidence' => 'true',
              )
   ),


];
```

i want to showing this all attr selected with true value in like this
also I want to sum price of `array2` member and `array1`

```html
<h2>graphic</h2>
<p>internal_evidence</p>
<p>technical_evidence</p>
<small>course price: 150</small>
<small>314</small> <!--  Price with selected evidence -->


<h2>3dmax</h2>
<small>course price: 300</small>
<!-- its not have attr evidence  -->

<h2>ICDL</h2>
<p>internal_evidence</p>
<small>course price: 480</small>
<small>490</small> <!-- Price with selected evidence -->
```

i try this but its don`t work properly

```php
$priceOfAttr = 0;
foreach($array2 as $key => $cat):


 echo "<h2>{$cat['name']}</h2>";


foreach($array1 as $pr):

    if($pr['course_id'] == $cat['id']):





    foreach($cat['attr'] as $m => $optionV):
          if($m == $pr['name'] && $optionV == "true"){
              echo $m .'<br>';
              $priceOfAttr += $pr['price'];
              //   echo  "<small>{$cat['price']}</small><br>";
             // echo   $cat['price'] + $pr['price']. "<br>";

          }
    endforeach;
  echo $priceOfAttr + $cat['price'] . '<br>';

    endif;



endforeach;


 echo '<br>';


endforeach;
```

Comment: `<small>` value is plus all attr member with true value with the price of same member in `array1` and course price in `array2`

Comment: OK . `graphic` member array have a price `150` but this item have two attr with true value `internal_` and `technical_`  in `array1` `internal_` have price '30' and `technical` have price '134' . `graphic` section price sum all this prices

Comment: ture. i edit my question. i think its clearer

Comment: Can you please share what you have already tried?

Comment: I edit my post and showing my tried

Comment: Are `true` and `false` really represented as strings (as opposed to actual booleans)?

Comment: Yes because it can be change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a combination `array_reduce` and `array_map` to transform your data into what you need, then simply loop over that to display your view:

```
<?php

// Index your $array1 by [id][name]
$array1ByIdAndName = array_reduce($array1, static function ($byIdAndName, $entry) {
  $byIdAndName[$entry['course_id']][$entry['name']] = $entry;
  return $byIdAndName;
});

// Transform $array2's `attr` entries into attribute list + compute total price
$array2 = array_map(static function ($entry) use ($array1ByIdAndName) {
  $entry['total_price'] = $entry['price'];
  $entry['attr'] = array_reduce(array_keys($entry['attr']), static function ($attrs, $attrName) use ($array1ByIdAndName, &$entry) {
    if ($entry['attr'][$attrName] === 'true') {
      $attrs[] = $attrName;
      $entry['total_price'] += $array1ByIdAndName[$entry['id']][$attrName]['price'];
    }
    return $attrs;
  }, []);
  return $entry;
}, $array2);

// Display your view
?>

<?php foreach ($array2 as $entry): ?>

<h2><?= $entry['name'] ?></h2>
<?php foreach ($entry['attr'] as $attrName): ?>
<p><?= $attrName ?></p>
<?php endforeach ?>
<small>course price : <?= $entry['price'] ?></small>
<?php if ($entry['total_price'] > 0): ?>
<small><?= $entry['total_price'] ?></small>
<?php endif ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

**Demo: https://3v4l.org/nS3Gl**

Comment: if i want to show price for everyone attr what i have to do?